# Border Legend Same As Map Backgorund

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-pro, legend, borders

How create legend border same as map background like in the image? I'm just can get the border white like the rest of legend frame. I'm trying in Arcmap and ArcGIS Pro.
[image]

Comment: Are you saying you dont want that transparent piece, or you don't want the outer white piece?

Comment: I do want the transparent piece.

Comment: Under Legend Properties, experiment with the border off-set settings.